# No forwarder input on Graylog web interface after upgrade to enterprise

Tags: graylog, graylog3

I've upgraded to Graylog enterprise edition (free license) to play around with graylog. I'm hoping to forward from one cluster (which is NOT enterprise, and is already ingesting messages), to another cluser (which is enterprise).

I've downloaded graylog-server-enterprise, as well as added the enterprise license to the web api, but when I go to inputs, theres no forwarder input for me to use on the enterprise cluster. Have I missed something? Am I just not seeing it in the inputs dropdown??

I've tried setting up inputs with the same port number as the forwarder, but no luck with that.

There's simply no input for forwarded messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Since it was quite clear on the docs
I didn't install integration plugins, only the enterprise ones.

http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/integrations/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

What version of Graylog are you using? You must use v3.01 or later in order to have the Forwarder Input available.

Comment: I'm on version 3.02